# Publishing messages to specific aws-iot-core device from Lambda

Tags: node.js, aws-iot

I have a few iot devices registered in my iot-core env.
I am trying to invoke a method on a specific one by invoking a lambda in the cloud that is publishing mqtt topic. obviously the problem is that all my devices (which are sharing the same code) listen to the same topics.

How can I target my msg to a specific device?

This is the code that I am running in the lambda:

```
exports.handler = async (event, context, callback) => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    var AWS = require('aws-sdk');
    var iotdata = new AWS.IotData({endpoint: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxx.iot.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com'});

    var params = {
        topic: 'mytopic',
        payload: 'mypayload',
        qos: 0
    };

return iotdata.publish(params, function(err, data) {
    if(err){
        console.log(err);
    }
    else{
        console.log("Success, I guess.");
        //context.succeed();
    }
});

//  });
//};
```

Answer (score 0):

Put the device name you are targeting in the payload. Then your device code must check the payload for the device name.

Comment: sounds like a bad plan to check every incoming message on all devices.

Comment: If all your other devices listen to the same topics then there is no other way to do it. Alternatively, you can have each device subscribe to an additional unique topic, then just publish to that device's topic.